# 'parcel' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

So I'm following this repo(https://github.com/RasaHQ/chatroom). Really an amateur at node.js. Installed node.js from the windows installer and used npm install for installing yarn. Now when I do yarn build I get the error mentioned in the title.[image]

edit: adding another Screenshot.
[image: Installation of yarn]

edit2: adding screenshot of building yarn for the first time
[image]

Comment: Run `yarn` first to install the dependencies.

Comment: Adding 2 more screenshots @AKX

Comment: That project seems to use dependencies which aren't compatible with modern versions of Node.js (which is simplifying the situation a bit). You could look for alternatives (e.g. `sass` succeeds `node-sass`), but slotting those dependencies into place may prove tricky.

Comment: Can I do it by using a previous build of node.js?(if yes, could you please suggest a version)